# ASP.NET MVC: How to pre-select a jQuery-UI tab depending on the value of a model-property?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

Let's say I've the below marks up obtained by using values of some Model's properties:

```
<div id = "tabs">
 <ul>
     <%foreach(var category in Model.Categories){%>
       <li><a href = "#category.Name">category.Name</a></li>
     <%}%>
 </ul>
 <%foreach(var category in Model.Categories){%>
    <div id = "category.Name">
       //Content for each category goes here....
    </div> 
 <%}%>
</div>
```

Using JQuery I'm able to create easily a tabs widget

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
```

The Model contains also a property called **ListOfListArticle**, which is a list of a list of articles. Articles in the inner-list are grouped by category. There's also an other property called **ArticleToDisplay**.

```
public List<List<Articles>> ListOfListArticle { get; set; }
public Article ArticleToDisplay { get; set; } 
public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
```

I'd like to check first the category to which the article to display belongs and be able to automatically select the tab corresponding to that category. For now, when the page loads, the first tab is always selected.

Any way to deal with this?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#tabs").tabs(
    { selected: <%=Model.Categories.IndexOf(Model.ArticleToDisplay.Category) %> }
);
```

might be better to make that a property on your Model

```
public int Index 
{ 
    get 
    {
        if (Categories == null || ArticleToDisplay == null || ArticleToDisplay.Category == null) 
            return 0;

        return Categories.IndexOf(ArticleToDisplay.Category); 
    } 
}
```

then you can just write:

```
$("#tabs").tabs(
    { selected: <%=Model.Index %> }
);
```

Comment: I'm a little lost. What's this checking? the tab or the content?

Comment: make sense now? What it's doing is getting the index of the Article category which should be the same as how you iterate through it to generate your tabs

Answer (score 1):

I had same requirement.
I used a hidden field and then JS to get that value to set the jquery ui tab

1) I put a hidden field on the form ...

```
<%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EnmCreateCaseTab) %>
```

2) I have a javascript code bespoke for the page, which wraps js for the whole page, hence at the top of the page I have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.onReady(function () {
        var page = MyApp.newMyPage();
        page.Setup();
    });
</script>
```

( This is javascript classes in the style of Douglas Crockford ... )
Either the ctor or the page.Setup() fn then calls a private fn that gets the value of the hidden control and sets the tab with javascript

```
var SelectInitiallySelectedTab = function () {
        var formValueEnmCreateCaseTab = $("#EnmCreateCaseTab").val();
        // ...
        // set a jquery tabs control
        SelectTab(tabNum);
}
var SelectTab = function (tabNum) {
        // ensure tabNum is in bounds
        var tabCount = TabCount();
        var maxTabIndex = tabCount - 1;
        tabNum = tabNum < 0 ? 0 : tabNum;
        tabNum = tabNum > maxTabIndex ? maxTabIndex : tabNum;
        $('#tabs').tabs({ selected: tabNum });
    }
```

The hidden field, can be used to retain the user selected tab across re-submits ...

Answer (score 0):

just add `ui-tabs-selected` class to intended `<li>` element.

for details see following stack overflow page

[Opening page with tab preselected that's not the first tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932478/opening-page-with-tab-preselected-thats-not-the-first-tab/15159489#15159489)